# C, #include and #define override

Tags: c, include

I have a library as this:

```
mylib
  |__ device
        |__ lcd.h
        |__ lcd_config.h
        |__ lcd.c
```

.

```
// File lcd.h
#include lcd_config.h

void function initLcd();
void function writeLcd();
```

.

```
// File lcd.c
#include lcd.h

void function writeLcd(){
     // some code
}
```

.

```
// File lcd_config.h inside mylib
#ifndef lcd_config_H
#define lcd_config_H

#define TEST 10

#endif
```

I want to use the library in a project, but I want to redefine the configuration file.

```
myproject
    |__ lcd_config.h
    |__ mylcd.c
    |__ main.c
```

.

```
// File lcd_config.h inside myproject(at main.c level)
#ifndef lcd_config_H
#define lcd_config_H

#define TEST 20

#endif
```

.

```
// File mylcd.c
#include lcd.h

void function initLcd(){
     printf("%d", TEST);
}
```

.

```
// File main.c
#include "device/lcd.h"

int main(void) {
    initLcd(); // print 10
}
```

.

```
// File main1.c
#include "lcd_config.h"
#include "device/lcd.h"

int main(void) {
    initLcd(); // print 10 too
}
```

In my project i want that TEST = 20,  how can i achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Look at file now, this is my real case.

To print TEST=20 i have to put `#include lcd_config.h` before `#include lcd.h` inside `mylcd.c`.
If i put it in main file(like main1.c) 10 will be print, s i think preprocessing look before inside mylcd.h that main.c.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include the header that defines the TEST to 20 first. Beware that the `#ifndef` conditions will prevent the second header from actually doing anything, this is why in your case the value of TEST remains 10.

In some more detail, the block below says "this header should only be included in the project once". Defining the second header with the same clause in it will not change things if that header is included after the first one.

```
#ifndef lcd_config_H
#define lcd_config_H
...
#endif
```

I think the whole situation looks strange, though, there shouldn't be too headers with exactly the same name.

Comment: But i'm using lcd_config inside my project at first...so TEST should be equals 20. Why this is strange? I have a configuration file for a device, but i want to reconfig it in my current project if i want...it's normal i think.

Comment: look at file main1.c, i'm including lcd_config.h first, and this file is inside my project, not inside mylib.

Comment: @blow if that's an external parameter to the library, it should be possible to set it as one. The library in this case might contain something like `#ifndef TEST #define TEST 10 #endif`, i.e. only set it to the default value if not specified by the user.

Comment: @blow if the files are exactly as shown here, it's very strange, the output should be `20`. Can you make sure that your header actually gets included? E.g. using #warning next to the define itself?

Comment: yes file is there, i think i found the problem, main.c file is not the first file compiled i think the problem is gcc linker order, may be linker first "view" inside lcd.h and after inside main.c?

Comment: try adding `#warning test=20` where you define the TEST to 20 and a similar one where you define it to 10, then gcc will output that when compiling

Comment: Update, this is my real case now, ad seem that preprocessing look before inside mylcd.c and after inside main.c, so will bel included lcd_config.h of mylib first.

Comment: @blow, yes, if you don't include any header that defines TEST directly into one of your .c files, than the result will depend on the order in which things are compiled. In any case, I suggest that you reconsider -- having two different headers with the same `#ifndef` clause if definitely a bad practice, as is *overriding* the header present in the library. As a replacement, I suggest conditional define as in my example earlier so that there would be no chance of having two different values of `TEST` in the same program.